# React custom hook returning array and utilize the same in App component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have my App component defined as below;

```
function App() {
    const [state1, setState1] = useState({});
    const [state2, setState2] = useState({});
    const [isApiCallDone, setIsApiCallDone] = useState(false);

    const fetchFn = useMyCustomFetch();

    useEffect(() => {
        (async function() {
            try {
                let [state11] = await fetchFn('api/api1', {}, 'GET');
                let [state22] = await fetchFn('api/api2', {}, 'GET');
                setState1(state11); // Is there a better way to set this ?
                setState2(state22);
                setIsApiCallDone(true);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
        })();
    }, []);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (Object.keys(state1).length > 0 && Object.keys(state2).length > 0) {
            // Set some other state variables on App
        }
    }, [state1, state2])
    
    
    return (
        <>
            <MyContextProvider>
                    {isApiCallDone && (
                        <MyComponent />
                    )
                    }
            </MyContextProvider>        
        </>
    
}
```

Also my useMyCustomFetch hook looks like below

```
export default function useMyCustomFetch() {
    const fetchData = async (url, reqData, reqType) => {
        try {
            var statusObj = {
                statMsg: null
            };
            const response = await fetch(url, reqOptions);
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw response;
            }
            statusObj.status = "success";
            const json = await response.json();
            return [json, statusObj];
        } catch (error) {
            statusObj.status = "error";
            return [null, statusObj];
        }

    }
    return fetchData;
}
```

My questions are;

1. For the lines

   let [state11] = await fetchFn('api/api1', {}, 'GET');
   setState1(state11);

I first assign it to a new variable state11 and then assign the same by calling setState1.
Is there a better way to set the state1 directly?

2. Is the usage of async function inside the useEffect fine ?

Comment: Your custom hook...is not a hook : ) just a regular JS function, that returns a function. You can just import it and use it (without the wrapper around `fetchData`).

Answer (score 1):

For Question 1:

You can directly setState like below without using state11.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      try {
        setState1(
          (await fetchFn("https://reqres.in/api/users/1", {}, "GET"))[0]
        ); // Is there a better way to set this ?
        setState2(
          (await fetchFn("https://reqres.in/api/users/2", {}, "GET"))[0]
        );
        setIsApiCallDone(true);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    })();
  }, []);
```

For Question 2:

I don't see any problem using async & IIFE in the useEffect. In fact I like the way its done. Looks good to me.

Please find screenshot of the state being set properly in the console (I have used a dummy api url):

[image]

Comment: NO. The array is destructuring, so the state is the first element ! Here the state will be an array of elements.

Comment: The api you use returns an object, while the api the guy uses returns an array, we can see that by the array destructuring.

Comment: @LukasLaudrain - I see what you are saying. You are right! I have edited the response to pick [0] from array and seems to be alright. Thanks! Do let me know if you still see an issue.

Comment: @AdityaAkella - Thanks a lot...Could you please explain what this return statement is actually returning i.e. return [json, statusObj]...Is it pure array and we are destructuring it by using [0] ? Any similar simple example to correlate would be really helpful.

Comment: @copenndthagen - In my example I used this dummy api (reqres.in/api/users/1) from internet. This gives back response as an object with two attributes - {data: {...}, support:{...}}. Now the useMyCustomFetch in your question seems to return a pure array of [json, statusObj] i.e., [{data: {...}, support:{...}}, {status: 'success'}] ([response from api, custom status object]). I am just taking the [0] out of it, as you need only json data from api. Do let me know if I didn't make it clear. I will try again. Happy to help :)

Comment: @copenndthagen Was I able to clear your understanding. If so do give a thumbs up. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @AdityaAkella....yes, your explanation seems very awesome...However, for some reason, I am seeing an error when trying on my local..Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: @copenndthagen - Do you want to share error log & code? Let me know if you need some help!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use async functions, you can use the `Promise.prototype.then()` method to combine your calls like this :

```js
useEffect(() => {
    fetchFn('api/api1', {}, 'GET').then(state => {
        setState1(state[0]);
        return fetchFn('api/api2', {}, 'GET')
    }).then(state => {
        setState2(state[0]);    
        setIsApiCallDone(true);
    }).catch(console.log);
}, []);
```

An other way to set this with an async function but more factorised is this way :

```js
useEffect(() => {
    (async function() {
        try {
            await fetchFn('api/api1', {}, 'GET')
                .then(tab => tab[0])
                .then(setState1);

            
            await fetchFn('api/api2', {}, 'GET');
                .then(tab => tab[0])
                .then(setState2);

            setIsApiCallDone(true);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    })();
}, []);
```

Finally, the usage of the async function in an `useEffect` is not a problem.